# Is there a limit on the query response size when using Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, graphql

I'm using AWS Appsync with Elasticsearch. I'm aware that the max query size when using DynamoDB as the data source is capped at 1mb. Does the same limit imply when using Elasticsearch as a data source?

Answer (score 4):

In short, Yes.

I was just browsing around AppSync limits myself and saw this question was unanswered.

The limit is an AppSync limit, so no matter your choice of DataSource (VTL directly to Dynamo, Lambda to any data source, etc), AppSync won't allow you to send of receive over 1MB of data. So you'll have to page the results